# Groovy Email client to work on both Exchange 2003 and Exchange 2010

Tags: email, grails, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I need to implement a feature in my application to process an email, that I need to read by logging into the Exchange server. My question is what is the way to make my solution to work in both Exchange 2003 and 2010?

In near future my exchange sever may get upgraded

Note: I cannot use Imap, POP, etc...

I can use only Mapi or EWS.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be several options in Java to do this but no groovy specific ones. Pick one of them and use it from your groovy code. I haven't tried any of these but have a look at all the exchange providers listed on [this page](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/Third_Party.html)